# Jacoco: IllegalStateException: Can't add different class with same name

Tags: android, junit, code-coverage, jacoco

I am trying to generate Jacoco XML reports for [this Android project](https://github.com/EventFahrplan/EventFahrplan). I am using the [gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-android-junit-jacoco-plugin) version 0.16.0 (latest as of today).
When I run the `jacocoTestReportMerged` task it fails with the following error:

```java
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while analyzing XmlPullParsers.class.
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzerError(Analyzer.java:170)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:142)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:165)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:201)
        at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.createBundle(ReportTask.java:570)
        at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.createReport(ReportTask.java:542)
        at org.jacoco.ant.ReportTask.execute(ReportTask.java:495)
        ... 210 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't add different class with same name: 
    info/metadude/android/eventfahrplan/network/serialization/XmlPullParsers
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.CoverageBuilder.visitCoverage(CoverageBuilder.java:107)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer$1.visitEnd(Analyzer.java:98)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(ClassVisitor.java:338)
        at org.jacoco.core.internal.flow.ClassProbesAdapter.visitEnd(ClassProbesAdapter.java:98)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:683)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:391)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:124)
        at org.jacoco.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:140)
        ... 215 more
```

I started configuring exclude rules such as ...

```groovy
junitJacoco {
    excludes = [
        "**/XmlPullParsers.*"
    ]
}
```

... but then the task fails at the next file - so this does not seem to be the correct way.

I also tried 0.17.0-SNAPSHOT and version prior to 0.16.0, without success though. Gradle 6.3 is used in this project.

How can I configure the Gradle plugin for my project?