# NetBeans - Maven - JaCoCo - Can't add different class with same name

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm just going to start this off with the links I have already checked:

> [Jacoco: IllegalStateException: Can't add different class with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781578/jacoco-illegalstateexception-cant-add-different-class-with-same-name)
>
> [jacoco : Cannot exclude classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163426/jacoco-cannot-exclude-classes)
>
> [JaCoCo test coverage: How to exclude a class inside jar from report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133116/jacoco-test-coverage-how-to-exclude-a-class-inside-jar-from-report)
>
> [JaCoCo Can't add different class with same name: org/hamcrest/BaseDescription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673356/jacoco-cant-add-different-class-with-same-name-org-hamcrest-basedescription)

These are just the SO questions I have checked, not to mention all the GitHub posts too..

I have spent 2 full days now trying to find the solution for *my* problem, but I have yet to find anything that works.

So the story goes like this:

1. NetBeans project for automation testing
2. The company I work for has a jar file
3. I used below command to include this jar file in my project:

```
    mvn install:install-file - 
    Dfile=C:\MavenSelenium\Automation_Framework\src\main\resources\Dependencies\java-api-1.0-jar-with- 
    dependencies.jar -DgroupId=this.jar.file -DartifactId=api-bundle -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

4. Added the dependency to the **pom.xml** file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>this.jar.file</groupId>
        <artifactId>api-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

5. Open CMD, go to the location of the NetBeans project
6. Execute the following maven command (Or Clean and Build Project in NetBeans):

```
    mvn clean verify
```

7. Everything goes fine, EXCEPT when JaCoCo tries to generate the report. Below is the error log:

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:report (report) @ Automation_Framework ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file C:\MavenSelenium\Automation_Framework\target\jacoco.exec
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.851 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-12-20T20:35:00+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:report (report) on project Automation_Framework: 
An error has occurred in JaCoCo report generation.: Error while creating report: Error while analyzing 

C:\MavenSelenium\Automation_Framework\target\classes\Dependencies\
java-api-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar@org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/SystemClock.class. 

Can't add different class with same name: org/apache/logging/log4j/core/util/SystemClock -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

8. The JAR file that is mentioned in the error above is the JAR file/dependency from my company
9. This is my pom.xml file:

```
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
        <groupId>Automation_Framework</groupId> 
        <artifactId>Automation_Framework</artifactId> 
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> 
        <packaging>jar</packaging> 
            
        <properties> 
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding> 
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> 
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> 
        </properties> 
         
        <dependencies>
             
            <!-- TestNG --> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>7.3.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
     
            <!-- Selenium Java -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                <version>3.141.59</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Selenium API -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.141.59</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Selenium Remote Driver -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                <version>3.141.59</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Selenium Chrome Driver -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
                <version>3.141.59</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Selenium Common -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-common</artifactId>
                <version>2.0b1</version>
            </dependency>
      
            <!-- Apache Commons Lang3 --> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.11</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Video Recorder --> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.automation-remarks</groupId>
                <artifactId>video-recorder</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Apache POI -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Apache POI OOXML-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- JCraft -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.55</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Extent - RX Java -->
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>io.reactivex.rxjava3</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Extent - Free Marker -->
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.30</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Extent - Lombok -->
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    <version>1.18.12</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Extent - GSON -->
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.6</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Apache JMeter Core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
                <version>5.4</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Apache JMeter Components -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_components</artifactId>
                <version>5.4</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Apache JMeter JOrphan -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jorphan</artifactId>
                <version>5.4</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Apache JMeter JUnit -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_junit</artifactId>
                <version>5.4</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Apache JMeter HTTP -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_http</artifactId>
                <version>5.4</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Apache HTTP Core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.14</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- XStream Core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
                <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.15</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Aerogear OTP -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.aerogear</groupId>
                <artifactId>aerogear-otp-java</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Appium Java Client -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
                <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Company Jar (API) -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>this.jar.file</groupId>
                <artifactId>api-bundle</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
                <exclusions>
                  <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                    <groupId>this.jar.file</groupId>
                    <artifactId>api-bundle</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
                </exclusions> 
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- Surefire Plugin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            </dependency>
    
    
        </dependencies>
        
        <!-- Extent - Maven Checkstyle Plugin -->
        <reporting>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.16</version>
                    <reportSets>
                        <reportSet>
                            <reports>
                                <report>checkstyle</report>
                            </reports>
                        </reportSet>
                    </reportSets>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
        
        <build>
            <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <executions>
                      <execution>
                        <id>default-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                          <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                      </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.8.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/util/SystemClock.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>report</id>
                            <phase>test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        
        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.1</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>jar</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.1</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>jar</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </profile>
        </profiles>
        
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>Central Repository</name>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>Central Repository</name>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <name>Automation_Framework</name>
    </project>
```

You'll notice I have an exclusion by the actual dependency jar for the company I work for:

```
<!-- Company Jar (API) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>this.jar.file</groupId>
        <artifactId>api-bundle</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
          <exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
            <groupId>this.jar.file</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-bundle</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
```

as well as by the JaCoCo plugin section

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/util/SystemClock.class</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <phase>test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

neither works (at least that I can tell).

I honestly don't understand the half of the "technical talk" that I read and I am sure with more reading throughout my time of investigating all of this, I will begin to understand it BUT I cannot wait until I magically figure it out, so I am hoping someone can assist.

It's the first time I have setup a project like this, so admittedly there's plenty for me to still learn.

Comment: The jar file which you have installed via install-file is a so called fat jar which means it has been built to contains several dependencies (which is a very bad practice) and result in problems. The solution is not to use such a jar file. The problem is: you can't use exclusions etc. on pom level because the dependency has no transitive dependencies and that's the issue here. Apart from having issues in your pom file (using plugins as dependencies which is simply wrong; defining src/main/java ? Why? ) Defining repositories in your pom file ? Belongs to your settings.xml file...

Comment: Why adding the maven-jar-plugin? It's already bound through default life cycle etc.

Comment: Thank you @khmarbaise for the replies. I honestly just didn't know any better to be honest. As mentioned, this is the first time I am setting up a project like this and so I am learning as I go along. 

Would it be too much to ask for you to provide an answer with explanation of the issues and how to fix them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I believe I found the cause for my issue..

As far as I can tell, it was due to the way in which I added/stored the external JAR file for my company.

The JAR file was in my project folder:

```
C:\MavenSelenium\Automation_Framework\src\main\resources\Dependencies\java-api-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I removed the file from this location AND I deleted it from my list of *actual* dependencies.

I then tried to use the initial command from before, but with the file now in my downloads folder:

```
    mvn install:install-file - 
    Dfile=C:\Users\{username}\Downloads\java-api-1.0-jar-with- 
    dependencies.jar -DgroupId=this.jar.file -DartifactId=api-bundle -Dversion=1.0 - 
    Dpackaging=jar
```

However, I did not see it appear under my dependencies.

THEN, I right clicked on my dependencies folder (the one that is defaultly created with the maven project) and I clicked "Add Dependency" as below:

[image]

[image]

After I did this, I saw the dependency added under dependencies AND I saw the pom.xml updated with the addition of this dependency as well.

Code added to pom.xml automatically:

```
        <!-- API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>this.jar.file</groupId>
            <artifactId>api-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```